# The urlHelper.RouteUrl is not producing Correct URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

When the links are generated Code is in the Indexx of the controller.
So the Link Are Generated in this form

```
Wk/Index/XX/YYYY
```

The url Code is

```
 url = urlHelper.RouteUrl("Wk", new { slug});
```

But i need the link will Be in This form

```
Wk/C/XXX
```

Here c is the other Action name
How can this be achieved.

My Global Asax Looks like

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" , id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Wk", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{slug}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Wk", action = "c", slug = "", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Book", // Route name
            "{controller}/{id}/{pageNo}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Book", action = "Index",id = UrlParameter.Optional,pageNo = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "UserArea", // Route name
            "{controller}/{slug}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "UserArea", action = "Index", slug = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: There are many ways. It will depend on how your routes are defined.

Comment: I need the link Wk/c/
c is action Name 
I Dont need Index as Action 
At Presend it is generating Wk/Index
Tell me any one method

Comment: how does your routing definition look like in Global.asax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var url = urlHelper.RouteUrl("Wk", new { action = "C", slug = "XXX" });
```

Comment: The default action is already set in `MapRoute()`. Why does framework require to explicitly specify it in `RouteUrl()`? This is so unnatural...

Comment: Does no one have an answer to the question from @UserControl